# I am passing the object from component to controller using angular and .NET facing issues of KindValue=Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular

I am passing the object from component to controller using angular and .NET but controller receiving ValueKind=Object I have tried to serialize and deserialize method too.

```
Angular Component code:
    import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})

export class LoginComponent {

  email: string;
  password: string;
  public http: HttpClient;
  public baseUrl: string;



  constructor(private _httpService: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string)

 {
    this.http = _httpService;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    
  }

  public loginUser()
  {
   
 let data: any = {} as any;
    //console.log("Hello Login");
    //console.log(this.email);
    //console.log(this.password);
    
data.userEmail = this.email;
   
 data.userPassword = this.password;
    
//JSON.stringify(this.data);
    debugger;
   
 this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Login/GetUserLogin', data).subscribe(result => {
     
 console.log('my result is ='+result);
      
var l_arrResponse = result as any; //.json()
     
 console.log(l_arrResponse);
  
  }, error => console.error(error));
    
  }
        
}
.NET Controller code:

namespace DataFetchingFromControllerApp.Controllers
{
  
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class LoginController
    {
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable GetUserLogin([FromBody]dynamic p_oPostData)
        {
            //var test=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(p_oPostData);
             string enteredUserEmail = p_oPostData.userEmail;
             string enteredUserPassword = p_oPostData.userPassword;
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

In controller, p_oPostData containsValueKind=object by itself and below when i use p_oPostData.userEmail it gives exception.

Comment: Did you set set proper header for your request like `const headers: HttpHeaders = new  HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`?

Comment: i have initialized these in constructor.

Comment: But it seems you don't pass headers it should be like : `this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Login/GetUserLogin', data,  {headers: headers })`

Comment: If you repost your question about displaying decimal values as simple fractions, then I can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
p_oPostData.UserEmail //(the "U" uppercase)
```

Anyway, I would prefer declare a class `RequestLogin` with two properties and declare p_oPostData as RequestLogin, not as dynamic.

```
public class RequestLogin
{
   public string UserEmail {get;set;}
   public string UserPassword {get;set;}
}

//in your controller
public IEnumerable GetUserLogin([FromBody]RequestLogin p_oPostData){...}
```

NOTE: Forget headers.set('Content-type..) it's a error